# installing column unix utility on windows

Tags: software-installation, utilities, cygwin

I would like to be able to use the BSD unix utilities: column, join and paste in my Cygwin installation. It seems that they are not available, or I cannot find them. Is there a way to install them so I can use them on Windows?

Comment: `join` and `paste` are provided as part of the coreutils package, which is installed by default.  If you have `ls`, you should have `join` and `paste`.  Or are you looking specifically for the BSD versions of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cygwin is based on Linux, so its utilities come from the same packages as on Linux:

- `column` from [util-linux](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=util-linux%2Futil-linux-2.17.2-1)
- `join` and `paste` from [coreutils](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=coreutils%2Fcoreutils-8.14-1)

Comment: I'm sure coreutils is installed by default; it's the same package that provides `ls`, `rm`, `cp` et al, so the system wouldn't be very useful without it.

Comment: How do you find out which package they come from?

Comment: The package managers can tell you. With APT `dpkg -S \`which column\``, with PacMan `pacman -Qo \`which column\``. No idea how to find out without a Linux.

Comment: You can search Cygwin package content using the command `cygcheck -p` or this site: http://cygwin.com/packages. When searching for program names, it's usually a good idea to prefix them with "`bin/`", so as to exclude other stuff.

Comment: @ak2, thanks for mentioning `cygcheck`, I not met it before. Weird that it not lists _util-linux_ when searching for “column”, but lists _coreutils_ for “paste”. (Both are installed.)

Comment: @manatwork `cygcheck -p bin/column` lists nothing but three versions of _util-linux_. As I'd mentioned, if you omit the `bin/`, you're likely to get lots of other hits, which is why the first line of the output of `cygcheck -p column` says _Found 30 matches for column (search truncated due to too many matches)_.

Comment: @ak2 Oops. Sorry. I missed that notice. (Hard to notice it when you try to filter out the blah-blah with `grep 'util'`…)

Comment: On ubuntu 14.04, I found `column` is from `bsdmainutils` instead of `util-linux`. `ubuntu[0]:dpkg -S `which column`
bsdmainutils: /usr/bin/column`